# no rule to make target all in cpp in eclipse

Tags: c++

I have imported two folders which containing files of c++(more than 20 files of .cpp and their corresponding .h files) and which was already running somewhere else system but now when I imported it in my eclipse and trying to build,it giving following error:

```
make all 
make: *** No rule to make target `all'.  Stop.
```

Comment: So what's in your makefile? That seems the most relevant question. Do you even have a makefile?

Comment: The makefile probably simply doesn't have an `all` target. Please post a [mre]

Comment: If you are using Makefiles and you attempt to import 20 files and get them build, I would take a look at the makefile syntax and maybe build your own one. If that is too complex and time consuming for you , a good alternative I like to use for such imports is cmake.

Comment: @Excoder Then clearly the content of the makefile is not what eclipse is expecting. Eclipse expects a makefile taget called `all`. If you post the content of the makefile someone might be able to tell you what adjustments you need to make to make it compatible with Eclipse. I don't get it, you're having trouble with a makefile, why do you need to be told to post the makefile in the question? Sorry for the rant, but really I don't get it.

Comment: @ Dr.-Ing. Gerhard Stein, what if I make my own makefile for folder1(containing 20 files) and folder2(containing 20 files) separately and how to do this?

Comment: @john, if I delete that make file then how to create a new one?

Comment: @Excoder I am thinking that you might be able to make a small edit to your existing makefile, not rewrite it completely. But I can't see the makefile so what do I know.

Comment: You've error in your make file, if it is autogen based check that you've run ./configure before

Comment: @john, I want to write my own make file because I have deleted that old makefile.